# Question about an unusual inner product

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

Consider the space $C([0,1])$, given by the inner product 
$(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})g(\frac{1}{n})$. I want to show this is not an inner product, but I want to check which inner product axioms fail so I might be able to modify it.

Certainly if $f=0$, then $(f,f)=0$. Now if we let $f,g\in C([0,1])$, with $f,g>0$, then certainly the inner product $(f,g)>0$ because $(f,g)=f(1)g(1)+f(1/2)g(1/2)+...$ are all strictly positive.

However, this only works if $f,g$ are exclusively positive on $[0,1]$. Consider the constant functions $f=-1$ and $g=1$ with $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We get a sum with exclusively negative terms, and the series diverges tends to $-\infty$, so $(f,g)<0$ in some cases.

$(f,g)=(g,f)$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(1/n)g(1/n)$ certainly can be rearranged to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(1/n)f(1/n)$ by commutativity.

However, I am unsure how to rigorously check

$(3)$$(f+h,g)=(f,g)+(h,g)$

$(4)$ $(af,g)=a(f,g)$. I can show (3), (4) hold for polynomials, but I am unsure how to prove it for general continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Comment: A macroscopic problem is that $(f,g)=+\infty$ most of the times.

Comment: Can you construct a function $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $f(1/n)=0$ and $f\ne 0?$ (Of course, as @G.Sassatelli said it is not well defined.)

Comment: It's best not to call it an inner product at the beginning if the goal is to prove it's not an inner product.

Comment: Per @zhw,  we can call this a bilinear form rather than an inner product, to avoid self-contradiction.

Comment: @hardmath It's not a bilinear form either, is it?

Comment: @zhw:  It is a bilinear form on some subspace of $C ([0 1]) $ where the terms are square-summable.  The convergence is the only issue with it being a bilinear form or an inner product, but that is perhaps the point of asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define it on the space $S = \left\{f \in C[0,1] : \sum_{n=1}^\infty f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 < +\infty\right\}$ to ensure $(\cdot, \cdot) < +\infty$.

You have already checked $(0, 0) = 0$ and $(f, g) = (g, f)$.

Linearity also holds:

\begin{align}(\alpha f + \beta g,h) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\alpha f + \beta g\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\alpha f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \beta g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= \alpha \sum_{n=1}^\infty f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \beta \sum_{n=1}^\infty g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= \alpha(f, h) + \beta(g, h)
\end{align}

However, there are functions $f \in S$ such that $(f, f) = 0$, but $f \ne 0$.

An example is:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$} \\
x - \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $x \in \left\langle\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}\right]$}\\
1 - x, & \text{if $x \in \left\langle\frac{3}{4}, 1\right]$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: question about the details: For $x\in (1/2,1)$ if we use $(1/n)^2-1/2$ and $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ for $x\in (3/4,1)$, I don't see how $\sum_{n}f(1/n)^2$ goes to $0$ when we combine these sums. (Of course, $\sum_{n}f(1/n)^2=0$ on $(0,1/2)$

Comment: @Kernel_Dirichlet  I think you're confused about something. This particular $f$ has $f(1/n)=0$ for $n=1,2,\dots.$

Comment: I see it now, thanks!